# 2 lines listview filtering by both lines in android

Tags: android, listview, duplicates

I am doing filtering in list view where i have 2 lines. And I want to filter by both lines. If I have different Strings in both lines - filtering works fine, but if i have equals strings in both lines i am getting this list item duplicated while searching. What I can do to remove these duplicate items after filtering and have filtering by both lines?
Here is my code:

```
private void addToList(){

    allImplements = db.getAllImplements();
    Collections.reverse(allImplements);

    final List<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> map;
    for(Implement t: allImplements) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name", t.getName());
        map.put("type", t.getType());
        map.put("id", String.valueOf(t.getId()));
        map.put("icon", Integer.toString(t.getIcon()));
        listMap.add(map);
    }        
     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listMap, R.layout.equip_list_item, new String[] { "icon", "name", "type", "id"}, new int[] { R.id.icon, R.id.firstLine, R.id.secondLine, R.id.equip_id });
     listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your how adpater class that extends SimpleAdapter. you can then improve your filtering by overriding getFilter()

Comment: Maybe you can give me any examples of this?